# UITabBar not correctly updating orientation of one view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, orientation, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with 5 view controllers in it. When any of the first four controllers are selected and the device orientation changes, the view will correctly update.

However when the last controller is active and the device orientation changes, the frame of the view does not correctly update its size to the new frame size until I select another tab and then go back to the fifth tab. The view is "rotated" correctly, but it is clipped by the device because it has the incorrect frame size.

Also to answer a question before it is asked, I have the following code in the view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well I'm not sure if this is a bug or a problem in my code or the way everything is setup, BUT I've figured it out.

Apparently this happens for any view that I load from an XIB that's added to this tabBarController. I tested out with several other views and it only happened when views were added from XIBs. I've deleted that and built everything from code and it seems to be working now.